# Access Denied while trying to create mini-dump with WinDbg

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg, dump, crash-dumps

I am trying to create a mini-dump using WinDbg. After attaching to the process (non-invasive), I execute the following command:

`.dump /mA c:\Temp\app.dmp`

This results in the following error:

```
Creating c:\Temp\app.dmp - mini user dump
WriteFullMemory.Memory.Read(0xe730000, 0x10000) failed 0x8007012b, skip.
WriteFullMemory.QueryVirtual(0x0) for info failed, 0x80070005
Dump creation failed, Win32 error 0n5
    "Access is denied."
```

WinDdg is being run as an **Administrator**. We have the lastest version of WinDbg, we confirmed we're running the 64 bit version and the process being attached is 64 bit. Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

For context, we're taking the dump to isolate the root cause of a memory leak in one of our IIS-hosted WCF Web Services.

*Side note: this may be due to paged memory but not sure how to get around that.*

Comment: Could the app.dmp file be locked somehow?  Try a different directory/filename combination.

Comment: If you really use `/mA` instead of `/ma` then paged-out memory should not matter. Even if it can't page in (I'm not sure whether it should be able to do so), the error should be ignored. So this sounds more like a file/disk error to me. The C: disk is somewhat protected by UAC. Could you try a different disk? Is non-invasive required in your case? Can you dump in invasive mode?

Comment: Not sure why but switching to an invasive dump resolved the issue. Thanks.